# Include variables generated in first play of playbook

Tags: automation, ansible

I have a playbook which consists of two plays:
1: Create inventory file and variables file on localhost
2: Use the variables in commands on generated inventory

Example playbook:

```
---
- name: Generating inventory and variables
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
     -  variables.yml  #variables file used for automating
  tasks:
      - name: Creating inventory template
        template:
             src: hosts.j2
             dest: "./inventories/{{location}}/hosts"
             mode: 0777
             force: yes
        ignore_errors: yes
        run_once: true
      - meta: refresh_inventory
      - name: Creating predefined variables from a template
        template:
             src: predefined-vars.yml.j2
             dest: "./variables/predefined-vars.yml"

- name: Setting vlan to network devices
  remote_user: Ansible
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
     -  variables.yml  #variables file used for automating.
     -  variables/predefined-vars.yml 
  tasks:
      - name: configure Junos ROUTER for vlan
        include_tasks: ./roles/juniper/tasks/add_vlan_rt.yml
        when:
          - inventory_hostname in groups['junos_routers']
          - groups['junos_routers'] | length == 1
          - location == inventory_name
```

This gives undefined variable error (for a variable created in the first play).

Is there a way to do this? I use this for generating variables like router_port_name and so on - the variables depend on location and dedicated server, which are defined in variables.yml

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: However, I have noticed that this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  name: 1
  vars_files:
  - variables.yml

  tasks:
- name: Creating predefined variables from a template
    template:
         src: predefined-vars.yml.j2
         dest: "./variables/predefined-vars.yml"

- name: Generate hosts file
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
  - variables.yml
  - ./variables/predefined-vars.yml

  tasks:
  - name: test
    debug: msg="{{ router_interface_name }}"
```

show the variables created in the first play.

The difference I see is that the first playbook reads all variable files (even predefined-vars.yml <- created at first play, used at the other) used in the playbook at the start of the first play (generating inventory and creating variable file) while the second playbook reads variables.yml in first play and only at the start of the second play reads the predefined-vars.yml .

Any Ideas how to make the first playbook behave the same way?

Comment: Your example is too big. Try to make it manageable in size. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Noted and edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the solution to the problem, based on the documentation and suggestions from other people.

What I understood about the problem:

A playbook will read all the variables (of all plays) provided into the cache for later use, so if I include my predefined-vars.yml into vars_files, then after changing it in first play, the changes will not be used by later plays because they will use cache for that.

Thus I had to create another task in second play, which would read (load into cache) my newly generated file (for that play):

```
      - name: Include predefined vars
        include_vars: ./variables/predefined-vars.yml
        run_once: true
```

Hope this helps you!
Still have no idea why second play shows the variables...